# Javascript clearInterval in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am new to OOP in Javascript or jQuery, I am trying to clear the interval and stop any methods inside the interval, it seems not working with what I did below.

```
function Timer() {
    var sec = $('.timer #second');

    this.runTimer = function(_currentime) {
        var currentTimeing = parseInt($(_currentime).text());
        this.timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
            $('.projects li span.second').text(currentTimeing++)
        }, 1000); 

        $("#stop").click(function() {
            // clear interval
            clearInterval(this.timeInterval);
        })
    }
}

var play = new Timer();

$("#start").click(function(){
    //console.log(this.runTimer())
    play.runTimer('#second');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `this` in context of different functions, that's why it's not working fine. Try:

```
 function Timer() {

    var sec = $('.timer #second');

    this.runTimer = function(_currentime) {

      var currentTimeing = parseInt($(_currentime).text()), that = this;
      that.timeInterval = setInterval(function(){
        $('.projects li span.second').text(currentTimeing ++)
      }, 1000); 

      $("#stop").click(function(){
        // clear interval
        clearInterval(that.timeInterval);
      })
    }
  }

  var play = new Timer();

  $("#start").click(function(){
    //console.log(this.runTimer())
    play.runTimer('#second');
  })
```

I'm simply saving reference to correct `this` in `that` variable, so I can later use it to clear interval.

Comment: no need for `that.timeInterval` at all, I'd just make it a normal var.

Comment: Indeed, with this code, there is no need at all, but maybe author have some further plan to develop this code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function Timer() {

    var sec = $('.timer #second');
    var timeinterval;   // declare timeinterval variable here
    this.runTimer = function(_currentime) {

      var currentTimeing = parseInt($(_currentime).text());
      timeInterval = setInterval(function(){
        $('.projects li span.second').text(currentTimeing ++)
      }, 1000); 

      $("#stop").click(function(){
        // clear interval
        clearInterval(timeInterval);
      })
    }
  }

  var play = new Timer();

  $("#start").click(function(){
    //console.log(this.runTimer())
    play.runTimer('#second');
  })
```